# Making tiles different size

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, grid

I currently have a `Universal Windows Application` that is dynamically creating `GridViewItems` inside of a `GridView`. The `GridViewItems` in my case are tiles and the tiles are all the same size (because I am setting them that way in my XAML via Width and Height).

I am wanting to have different sized tiles, not tiles that are all the same size, to give it the Windows 8/10 look and feel.

I will posy my current code below:

```
<GridView x:Name="tileGridView" Margin="-15,60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A"
                                  Margin="5"
                                  Height="200"
                                  Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can create the tiles in different sizes, and them not all be the same size. I have read into the `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, but is that a Windows 8 functionality that did not get transferred to Windows 10 development?

**Update**

I have tried this, and I did not get the result I was looking for. It was giving me the same layout as I was getting with my above XAML.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: You mean [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid)? Yea it's there I'm pretty sure. There's even some GridView based [stuff](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da65cc08-c4bf-4824-b483-9c8f53fb063c) I've seen but never used.

Comment: Well give it a shot and come on back if it doesn't offer a remedy.

Comment: @ChrisW. I added my above update

Comment: Different size based on _what_?

Comment: I would just want different sizes at random... I do not really care under what circumstances it becomes a different size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, you'll want to use a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` for that.

You will still need to assign a `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` to each tile. Their defaults are "1", meaning they will all have the same size.

Take a look at this detailed example for more information on how to achieve this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walaa/archive/2014/02/23/gridview-amp-multiple-item-templates.aspx

EDIT: Another option is to do something like this:

Create your own GridView:

```
public class VariableGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var gridViewSize = item as IGridViewSize;
        if (gridViewSize != null)
        {
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, gridViewSize.ColumnSpan);
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, gridViewSize.RowSpan);
        }

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

`IGridViewSize` is defined as followed:

```
public interface IGridViewSize
{
    int ColumnSpan { get; }
    int RowSpan { get; }
}
```

Implement this interface in your tiles. And when creating your items, assing your (random) values to their `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan`.
(An alternative would be: ignore this interface, and assign your random sizes inside the `VariableGridView.PrepareContainerForItemOverride` method.)

You can use this `VariableGridView` as such:

```
<controls:VariableGridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <controls:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </controls:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
</controls:VariableGridView>
```

Comment: I am failing to see how that would work in my case? I do not have a hard coded amount of tiles that I can set the row/columnspan manually. My Tiles are generated dynamically, depending on the amount of objects in my returned list....

Comment: @Code You can add your randomization inside the `HomeTemplateSelector` (in that example). Another option is to define a `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` property in each tile object and create a custom `VariableSizedGridView` that grabs these spans and assign them to the correct properties. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: Are you sure that this will work for a Windows 10 application? The example link looks like it is for developing a Windows 8 applicaiton

Comment: @Code, yes, it'll work on W10, as well as W8 and W8.1